# Cannot select repository to commit to

Tags: macos, svn, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I`m using **Xamarin Studio 4.0.12 build 3** to create iOS and Android apps.

But, I think since the last update, SVN doesn't work correctly anymore.

If I create a new project and want to add it to our SVN server, I can't select our SVN repository and I'm not sure where the commits go (local maybe?).

So, how can I commit the project to our SVN server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update, command line tools are not installed (appropriate version). So, in Xcode, under Preferences dropdown menu, in downloads, find Command line tools and download and instal it.